# webservice xml request in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I need to implement a webservice that get as request the following xml

```
<EVG_CardValid>
  <Token>
    <UserName>xxxx</UserName>
    <password>yyyy</password>
    <CardID>71656</CardID>
  </Token>
  <MaxTitle>5</MaxTitle>
  <IncludeDates>
    <startDate>2012-11-25T13:06:33.11</startDate>
    <EndDate>2012-11-25T15:06:33.11</EndDate>
  </IncludeDates>
</EVG_CardValid>
```

the webservice need to response back an xml

```
 <info>
    <cardName>
    xxx
    </cardName>
    <cardValidDate>1/1/2013</cardValidDate>
    ...
    </info>
```

I am new to webservices(only use local wcf with jason)

My question is How sholud my webservice look like ,what do I have to execpt as parameters in my function(what variables for the mentioned xml)
how do I send the xml as response(send back string built as xml?)

Do I have to do something special When checking username and password from database ?

What is better to use in this case wcf or webservice?

sorry for the ignorance,any help will be very appreciated

Thanks a lot
Baaroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same kind of requirement earlier, I posted in my blog, check it once..

It might help you getting started.

http://www.iamraghuveer.com/2012/01/aspnet-web-service-receiving-xml-as.html

There is some junk also in that post, But it is working approach.